# Publishing my book

Tags: creative-writing, publishing, novel, young-author

my name is Ash, and I'm 14, I've been writing since I was in sixth grade, well, I mean I've been writing over 500 words since sixth grade. I have written small little books that had no plot whatsoever at age eight.

I am hoping to get one of two books published, though I believe that both of them will be completed when I'm over 15 years old, but I may be wrong. I have been wrong before.

I currently write one update every week for each book, one I have completely planned out, and is at least over 1,200 words for each chapter and there are 75 including bonus chapters.

Do you think I have a chance to publish my books? Be blunt with me, I don't like sugar coated things.

Answer (score 2):

You could definitely get published in a junior anthology that recognises talent/prolificness for your age, but being frank, most young teenagers (and old teenagers, people in their 20s, etc) don't have the life experience to write compelling stories, and even if you're an exception, publishers are going to see your age and make assumptions.

Either your work is truly kick-ass and they'll stop caring, or they'll reject you. If they're nice, they're likely to refer you to junior anthologies as I alluded to above.

Don't let me discourage your passion, though; if you start young, you'll only grow more with time. You'll be publishable with time and self-awareness; once you become old and self-critical enough to find your flaws and what edges you need to hone, you'll grow to the point where publication isn't just on the cards, but highly likely.

Comment: Thank you for being frank with me. I understand that stereotypes with my young age are still prominent at this time of society. Thank you for your help and support. This means a lot to me as I have not been able to get blunt words before. I will be sure to look into those junior anthologies.